# Planets and moons positions in cartesian coordinates?

Tags: solar-system, planet, data-analysis

Is there freely available and reliable source, where one can find positions of planets and moons of the Solar system at given time in cartesian coordinates? (I am writing a simple gravity simulator and it would save me a lot of work with conversion.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Horizons Ephemeris Generator](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi)

Here is a screen capture where vector option is chosen:

[image]